# how to add my location button to google map

Tags: html, google-maps

i would like to add my location button to my map like the real google map does. 
ihave tried some plugins but they didnt had location button, what should i do?
here is one plugin that i used:

```html
var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 17,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
    mapOptions);
var GeoMarker = new GeolocationMarker(map);
```

Comment: Do you mean the put up a Marker on a location on maps?, if  so , read this documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple

Comment: i mean just like google map on phones, add a button and when click it jump to my location

Answer (score 2):

For web browsers you can use the html5 built in geolocation to get your location: You can follow this doc: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation

But first set a default location in case the browser doesn't support Geolocation

```
var myLocation = {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644};
```

After that in your init function you can get your location like this:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

      myLocation.lat = position.coords.latitude;
      myLocation.lng = position.coords.longitude;
      map.setCenter(myLocation);

      }, function() {
      handleLocationError(true, map.getCenter());
   });
} else {
   // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
   handleLocationError(false, map.getCenter());
}
```

Set your location's coordinates as default center of the map

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
   zoom: 17,
   center: myLocation,
   mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
});
```

Then just call this function if you want to go back to your location

```
function goToMyLocation() {
  map.setCenter(myLocation);
}
```

Check this working example: https://jsbin.com/ricebu/edit?html,css,js,output

Here is the code snippet as well

```js
var map;
var btnLocation = document.getElementById("btn-location");
var myLocation = {
  lat: -34.397,
  lng: 150.644
};

function initMap() {

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 17,
    center: myLocation,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

      myLocation.lat = position.coords.latitude;
      myLocation.lng = position.coords.longitude;

      // I just added a marker for you to verify your location
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLocation,
        map: map
      });

      map.setCenter(myLocation);
    }, function() {
      handleLocationError(true, map.getCenter());
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleLocationError(false, map.getCenter());
  }
}

function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
  console.log(browserHasGeolocation ?
    'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
    'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
}


btnLocation.addEventListener('click', function() {
  goToMyLocation();
});

function goToMyLocation() {
  map.setCenter(myLocation);
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#btn-location {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#btn-location:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Location</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="btn-location">Go to my Location</button>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCKQX3cyZ7pVKmBwE8wiowivW9qH62AVk8&callback=initMap"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var btnLocation = document.getElementById("btn-location");
var myLocation = {
  lat: -34.397,
  lng: 150.644
};

function initMap() {

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 17,
    center: myLocation,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

      myLocation.lat = position.coords.latitude;
      myLocation.lng = position.coords.longitude;

      // I just added a marker for you to verify your location
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLocation,
        map: map
      });

      map.setCenter(myLocation);
    }, function() {
      handleLocationError(true, map.getCenter());
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleLocationError(false, map.getCenter());
  }
}

function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
  console.log(browserHasGeolocation ?
    'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
    'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
}


btnLocation.addEventListener('click', function() {
  goToMyLocation();
});

function goToMyLocation() {
  map.setCenter(myLocation);
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#btn-location {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#btn-location:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Location</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="btn-location">Go to my Location</button>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCKQX3cyZ7pVKmBwE8wiowivW9qH62AVk8&callback=initMap"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also consider using https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps-current-location

It adds the typical button to the map, it handles the geolocation, and it also adds the blue circle surrounding the marker.
Hope it helps :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).